# Spree : Multiple dropdowns for product options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

What is the current best practice to turn product options into multiple
dropdown lists?

For example a `T-Shirt` has a `Size` and a `Color` option.
How can I use 2 dropdown lists on product pages for them?
Is there a guide, or documentation about this?

The radio button based solution is not that user friendly, and can be quite
complex (and long) if there are many options.

So basically what I would like to do is display the options separately, and
not as a variant like `Green` color - `S` size but like this:
1st dropdown: `Color: Green`
2nd dropdown: `Size: S`

At the end of the day it doesn't have to be a dropdown, just would like to
display the options separately in the most user (buyer) friendly way.

[github.com/tuxdapenguin/spree_variant_options](http://github.com/tuxdapenguin/spree_variant_options)
This plugin might work but it looks like it hadn't been updated in a while

Comment: Which spree version are you using?

Comment: @Vishal using 3-0-stable

Comment: Yes there is no stable version of gem https://github.com/tuxdapenguin/spree_variant_options(3-3)

Comment: I have made this sizes in my way.

Here is the example you are looking for 

https://capbeast.com/products/flat-bill-snapback-new-era

 In gem they are using methods to bind the option value

<%= variant_options variant %>

you need to customize the code for view and send the variant id to add to cart form